# How to reduce a compact buffer in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, reduce

Here is my RDD:

```
scala> grouped_final_resultMap.first
res20: (String, Iterable[Float]) = (2014-02-01,CompactBuffer(239.96, 129.99, 49.98, 100.0, 399.98))
```

What I want to do is the sum up all the items in the `Iterable[Float]` in that RDD’s `_2`-nd component.

Can anyone tell me how can I do it?

Thank you very much.

---

**Update:**

Here is the repl session:

```
scala> final_result.take(20).foreach(println)
2828,2013-08-10,129.99
43399,2014-04-20,100.0
43399,2014-04-20,129.99
43399,2014-04-20,49.98
8989,2013-09-19,119.97

...

scala> val final_resultMap1 = final_result.map(x=>(x.split(",")(1), x.split(",")(2).toFloat))
scala> grouped_final_resultMap1.first
res34: (String, Iterable[Float]) = (2014-02-01,CompactBuffer(239.96, 129.99, ...

val sumed = final_resultMap1.map{case (str, nums) => (str, nums.sum)}
```

If gives the following error:

```
<console>:41: error: value sum is not a member of Float
   val sumed = final_resultMap1.map{case (str, nums) => (str, nums.sum)}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [`CompactBuffer`](https://github.com/eBay/Spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/collection/CompactBuffer.scala) extends `Iterable`, and [`Iterable`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Iterable.html) has a method `sum`, it should be as simple as:

```
grouped_final_resultMap.map{ 
  case (str, nums) => (str, nums.sum) 
}
```

However, make sure that you didn't miss the opportunity to perform this associative reduction operation in some previous step.

---

From your EDIT it is apparent that you don't want to do anything at all with the grouped_final_resultMap1, and instead you want something like

```
final_resultMap1.reduceByKey((_: Float) + (_: Float))
```

or just

```
final_resultMap1.reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

for short.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply:
scala> val sumed = grouped_final_resultMap1.map{case (str, nums) => (str, nums.sum)}
<console>:43: error: could not find implicit value for parameter num: Numeric[String]
         val sumed = grouped_final_resultMap1.map{case (str, nums) => (str, nums.sum)}
???

Comment: Is there any difference between "grouped_final_resultMap" and "grouped_final_resultMap1"? Did you swap the order of strings and compactBuffers or something like that?

Comment: same. I also just tried successfully make the numbers to toFloat so that they are float, and do the map again:scala> val sumed = final_resultMap1.map{case (str, nums) => (str, nums.sum)}
<console>:41: error: value sum is not a member of Float
         val sumed = final_resultMap1.map{case (str, nums) => (str, nums.sum)}

Comment: can you start a chat room maybe?

Comment: And `final_resultMap1` is again an `RDD[(String, Iterable[Float])]`? (it will give me a link to a chatroom if we post a few more comments here)

Comment: yes:scala> final_resultMap1
res33: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Float)] = MapPartitionsRDD[20] at map at <console>:39

Comment: I don't see how to start a new chatroom, I guess my account doesn't have the privilege yet

Comment: Well, an `RDD[(String, Float)]` is obviously not the same as an `RDD[(String, Iterable[Float])]`, so how does this fit together with your question, and in particular with the title of the question? Where did the `CompactBuffer`s go?

Comment: I think it would be better and more convenient to post the code in a chatroom, can you do so, I do not have enough points to do it

Comment: Here it is: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164922/reduce-compact-buffers-choix-tyukin

Comment: alright, I think I should start from beginning and apply your idea when needed, I will post update here, thank you.

Comment: It turns out I do not have enough point to even chat, anyway, thank you and like I said, I will post my update here.

Comment: Yeah, all those apparent limitations have a reason. It's a Q&A site, the idea is that you try to make your question sufficiently high-quality so that it is useful for everyone else encountering a similar problem. Try to formulate your problem more precisely, then update the question. And please markup code-blocks in the question.

Comment: start again:

scala> val final_resultMap1 = final_result.map(x=>(x.split(",")(1), x.split(",")(2).toFloat))
scala> grouped_final_resultMap1.first
res34: (String, Iterable[Float]) = (2014-02-01,CompactBuffer(239.96, 129.99, ...
val sumed = final_resultMap1.map{case (str, nums) => (str, nums.sum)}
<console>:41: error: value sum is not a member of Float
         val sumed = final_resultMap1.map{case (str, nums) => (str, nums.sum)}

Comment: Again: `grouped_final_resultMap1` seems to have nothing in common with `final_resultMap1`, it has an entirely different type, and it obviously cannot work this way. Please don't dump walls of code in the comment section, and update your question instead (there should be a small gray 'edit' button right under the question).

Comment: Thank you, the initial question was updated. as you can see, the data is (String, Iterable[Float])  and CompactBuffer with presumably Float

Comment: In your update, you don't show where "grouped_final_resultMap1" comes from, you simply extract the first value from it, and print it out. It doesn't seem to have anything in common with the `final_resultMap1`, on which you are calling the `map` function provided in my answer. I updated my answer with a `reduceByKey` operation which is applicable to `final_resultMap1`.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's the answer!

Comment: @Choix I've updated the formatting of your question a little bit, you might want to click on the "edited <time> ago"-link under your question, and take a look at the markdown formatting.